# Navigate through waypoints without stopping and shortcutting

Tags: ros2, path-planning, nav2, ros-galactic

I have experimented with NavThroughPoses, but I'm encountering challenges in narrow corridor navigation scenarios, eg. poses: [p1, p2, p3, p2, p1]. My goal is to ensure the robot visits all these poses without taking shortcuts and without stopping. But it might simplify the path to sequences like [p1, p1] or [p1, p2, p1] or just not move at all.

If I understand correctly, I might need to customize the GoalChecker and the Planner/Controller to avoid these shortcuts. One solution might be to feed the NavThroughPoses action server sequentially, but then I could just use NavToPose and check feedback with distance_remaining to request a new pose on-the-fly, before reaching the previous pose (to avoid stops).

How would you ensure that all poses in sequences like [p1, p2, p3, p2, p1] are visited in order without skipping duplicates and stops? What would I need to do to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

That feels like a controller tuning thing. If you want your robot to not skip over waypoints, don't allow the controller to do so. For example, the RPP controller is specifically designed just to follow a path more or less blindly (though will stop before collisions). DWB/TEB/MPPI would be overkill if you don't want to deviate, though you could tune DWB/MPPI to do the same thing, but seems like more steps with little functional benefit.